# Ivy Bridge support

Tags: windows-8, storage, ivy-bridge

I've couple of workstation class high-end Ivy Bridge (Intel Z77) based PCs. I'm wondering the level of Windows 8 support in regards to couple of key features such as:

1. Responsiveness Technologies - Rapid Start and Smart Connect
2. Rapid Storage Technology - Smart Response

These are quite essential for me to decide to go for new license. Any benchmarks are welcome.

Comment: This would depend on the exact CPU being used.

Comment: I use couple of 3700K and 3770 based machines

Comment: So look up what those products support on the Intel website.

Comment: We can only provide you answers to practical, answerable problems; not support or benchmarks.

Comment: I think I'm in a wrong place. Thanks for the barrage of -ve votes. I quit this place because something is wrong here. I'm blacklisting this site in my company, and I won't encourage my employees to use it. Thanks again

Comment: @akula You're asking the wrong questions. Please check the [faq] - it's clearly mentioned: _You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face._, _your questions should be reasonably scoped._ Your questions are more suited for discussions on how will x work on y, which is a bad fit for the site.

Comment: @akula: Read http://superuser.com/faq which explicitly mentions `Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site`, if you don't want to be constructive and actually learn and obtain useful results then there is nothing we can do for you. We aren't going to invest time when there's no gain for anybody or in people that don't care to do that tiny bit of research and homework, a **Question & Answer** site is essentially the wrong place to ask for benchmarks. We aren't affected by your rage quit or blacklisting, you're only doing this to yourself by being ignorant. Have a nice day

Answer (score 2):

I have one of these processors myself and have had no compatibility problems with the RTM version of Windows 8. I did have some overhead issues on earlier versions but it would seem Intel has been in communication with the Win8 dev team since Release Preview.

I do know RST is fully supported on Win8. Simply install the Win7 drivers until intel releases an "official" win8 version.

I do not know about rapid start since Windows 8 has its own method for trimming start times. What I do know is that I currently have Rapid Start enabled on the motherboard and my current boot times from cold off to login screen is about 20 seconds, 12 of which are loading my two raid controllers. NOTE: I am booting into an SSD so your mileage may vary.